# Selenium/Python:TypeError:undound method get()

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm a new in Python with Selenium. I tried to test my first python/selenium code and got an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
import time

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox

# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Here, I've got the error:

```
**TypeError:unbound method get() must be called with Webdriver instance as first argument (got str instance instead)**
```

Anybody knows how to tackle this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check your code for syntax errors? Did you read the docs for webdriver?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need `()` after `webdriver.Firefox` to actually call the class's constructor and create an instance.